# AngularJS Protractor E2E - mock httpBackend with absolute URLs

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have just started using Protractor to do E2E UI testing for an angularJS app.

The base url for the app looks something like -

```
http://localhost:8181/web-module/?username=admin
```

This url then redirects to the security-module in the actual application for the given username.  The security-module is running on a different port - 9191.

The redirected request looks like -

```
http://localhost:9191/security-module/user/?username=admin
```

When I try to mock this request using *$httpBackend* using -

```
  describe('Home Page', function () {
     var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
     var httpBackendMock = function () {
       var app = angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E']);
       app.run(function ($httpBackend) {       
         var current_user = {"username":"admin","password":null,"fullName":"System Admin","email":"admin@example.com"};
         $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:9191/security-module/user/?username=admin').respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
            return [200, current_user, {}];
         });

         $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();

       })
     };
     ptor.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock);

     it('home page', function () {
       ptor.get('http://localhost:8181/web-module/?username=admin');
       var element = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('username'));
       expect(element.getText()).toEqual('System Admin');
     }); 

  });
```

the GET call still tries to hit the actual http service/url rather than the mocked one.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Where is the mock code in your protractor side or in the app side ?

Comment: @gontard - By mock code, I guess you mean httpbackendMock definition.  All the code is in the spec javascript file under the 'describe' block       `   var httpBackendMock = function () {
    var app = angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['app', 'ngMockE2E']);
    app.run(function ($httpBackend) {}
`

Comment: Could you update your question, by providing a more complete example.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before. Use regex instead in your whenGET() method to make sure that any other parameter is there and you don't see it.

Try:

```
$httpBackend
.whenGET(/^http:\/\/localhost:9191\/security-module\/user.*$/)
.respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
   return [200, current_user, {}];
});
```

You will match all the urls which start with the regex path. Then, you can update your regex to specify only when there is *username=admin* as parameter. It's a pain to use regex with $httpBackend but this service only check parameters as a string.

To avoid writing each time:

```
/^http:\/\/localhost:9191
```

You can specify the baseUrl in your protractor.conf.js:

```
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9191',
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the redirection is performed? I think, that it should look like:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:8181/web-module/?username=admin')
.respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
    return [200, current_user, {}];
 });
```

because the application doesn't know about the redirection if it is done on the server side.